# Проблема с DOCTYPE

Tags: вёрстка, html, html5, doctype

Заметил я тут одну особенность, если задать DOCTYPE html запустить такой код в браузере:

```
<div style="width: 300px; border: 1px solid;">
  <input type="text" style="width: 100%;">
</div>
```

то input, начинает **чуть-чуть вылезать** из блока. Если же DOCTYPE убрать, то всё нормально. Насколько известным является этот баг (я например кое-как его вычислил)? И как с ним бороться (какой DOCTYPE ставить или как-то по-другому)?

UPD:

Методом тыка выяснил, что какой DOCTYPE не подставь, input всё равно будет вылезать :(.
Повторюсь: **без DOCTYPE всё ок**.

UPD2:

Выяснил, что проблема связана с т.н. "режимом совместимости". В этом режиме как раз и отображается всё как надо. Теперь вопрос: как отобразить как надо в обычном режиме?

Comment: DOCTYPE как девочки, все вроди одинаковые а дают по разному! Собственно и тут тоже самое)

Comment: Собственно, я это и так понимаю :). Но тут особый случай, как мне кажется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы, видимо, забыли про ширину границ `div`-а и `input`-а.
Именно на эти 4 пикселя (ширина правых и левых рамок)`input` и вываливается из родительского элемента.
На вскидку могу предложить лечение отрицательным правым `margin`-ом, фиксированной шириной `input`-а, либо удалением границ.

Upd: А не писать `DOCTYPE` - позволять браузеру отображать сайт как *ему* хочется, что не есть хорошо.

Upd:

простой вариант: написать `div`-у `padding-right:2px`

вариант с `JS`:

```
HTML:
...
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="input">
</div>
...

CSS:
#container {
  width:70%;
  border:1px solid;
}
#input {
  border:1px solid green;
}

JS: 
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var container = document.getElementById('container');
input.style.width = container.offsetWidth - 4 +'px';
```

Comment: Спасибо, отрицательный margin помог.

Comment: Простите, поспешил. Не очень то он помог, хотя по идее должен был. Про границы вы правы.

Comment: Добавьте побольше контекста в задачу, может быть смогу помочь с конкретной проблемой.

Comment: Ок, есть резиновый сайт. На этом сайте есть div, шириной 70%. Внутри div'а есть input, который должен быть растянут на весь div и не выходить за границы этого div'a. Жалко нельзя задать ширину типа (100% - 4px).

Answer (score 0):

Если вы говорите о "режимом совместимости", то я так понимаю, что речь идет о IE. В этом случае, я бы задавал принудетельно режим, в котором должен отображать страницу браузер. Ну, к примеру восьмой версии осла, прописываем так:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Comment: В режиме совместимости будет работать любой браузер, если не указать DOCTYPE. Вопрос заключался не в этом.